# Applying a custom function on data.table instead of using plyr and ddply

Tags: r, data.table, plyr

I'm processing a data.table named **orderFlow** and compute **potentialWelfare.tmp** as the output. So far, the following, plyr-based approach has been my solution, but due to the input **orderFlow** having millions of rows I would prefer a solution leveraging the performance of data.table in R.

```
    # solution so far, poor performance on huge orderFlow input data.table
    require(plyr)
    potentialWelfare.tmp = ddply(orderFlow, 
                       .variables = c("simulationrun_id", "db"), 
                       .fun = calcPotentialWelfare, 
                       .progress = "text", 
                       .parallel=TRUE)
```

Edit1: Briefly, the custom function checks whether there are more bids or asks in df and sums the valuation of *NbAsks* sorted (by valuation) bids. This is done to select the most valuable bids and sum up their valuation. The code is legacy, probably not very efficient, but it served its purpose in combination with plyr and ordinary data.frames.

```
    calcPotentialWelfare <- function(df){
       NbAsks = dim(df[df$type=="ask",])[1]
    #   print(NbAsks)
      Bids = df[df$type == "bid",]
    #         dd[with(dd, order(-z, b)), ]
      Bids = Bids[with(Bids,order(valuation,decreasing = TRUE)),]
      NbBids = dim(df[df$type == "bid",])[1]
    #   print(Bids)
      if (NbAsks > 0){
        Bids = Bids[1:min(NbAsks,NbBids),]
        potentialWelfare = sum(Bids$valuation)
        return(potentialWelfare)
      }
      else{
        potentialWelfare = 0
        return(potentialWelfare)
      }
    }
```

Unfortunately, I cannot find a working way to implement this using data.table. What I have arrived at so far using the ?data.table and the corresponding FAQ is this:

```
    #   trying to use data.table, but it doesn't work so far.
    potentialWelfare.tmp = orderFlow[, lapply(.SD, calcPotentialWelfare), by = list(simulationrun_id, db),.SDcols=c("simulationrun_id", "db")]
```

what I get is

```
    Error in `[.data.frame`(orderFlow, , lapply(.SD, calcPotentialWelfare),  : unused arguments (by = list(simulationrun_id, db), .SDcols = c("simulationrun_id", "db"))
```

Here is the input:

```
    > head(orderFlow)
      type  valuation price               dateCreation                    dateDue                dateMatched id
    1  ask 0.30000000   0.3 2012-01-01 00:00:00.000000 2012-01-01 00:30:00.000000 2012-01-01 00:01:01.098307  1
    2  bid 0.39687633   0.0 2012-01-01 00:01:01.098307 2012-01-01 00:10:40.024807 2012-01-01 00:01:01.098307  2
    3  bid 0.96803384    NA 2012-01-01 00:03:05.660811 2012-01-01 00:06:26.368941                       <NA>  3
    4  bid 0.06163186    NA 2012-01-01 00:05:25.413959 2012-01-01 00:09:06.189893                       <NA>  4
    5  bid 0.57017143    NA 2012-01-01 00:10:10.344876 2012-01-01 00:57:58.998516                       <NA>  5
    6  bid 0.37188442    NA 2012-01-01 00:11:25.761372 2012-01-01 00:43:24.274176                       <NA>  6
              created_at updated_at simulationrun_id db
    1 2013-12-10 14:37:29.065634         NA             7004  1
    2 2013-12-10 14:37:29.065674         NA             7004  1
    3 2013-12-10 14:37:29.065701         NA             7004  1
    4 2013-12-10 14:37:29.065726         NA             7004  1
    5 2013-12-10 14:37:29.065750         NA             7004  1
    6 2013-12-10 14:37:29.065775         NA             7004  1
```

I am expecting something like this as the output, i.e., the function calcPotentialWelfare is aggregating data in a somehow special way from the column 'valuation' of the data.table orderFlow.

```
    > head(potentialWelfare.tmp)
      simulationrun_id db potentialWelfare
    1                1  1         16.86684
    2                2  1         18.44314
    3                4  1         16.86684
    4                5  1         18.44314
    5                7  1         16.86684
    6                8  1         18.44314
```

Really excited to see this get solved.
Thanks for reading!

Edit2:

```
    > dput(head(orderFlow))
    structure(list(type = c("ask", "bid", "bid", "bid", "bid", "bid"
    ), valuation = c(0.3, 0.39687632952068, 0.968033835246625, 0.0616318564942726, 
    0.570171430446081, 0.371884415116724), price = c(0.3, 0, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA), dateCreation = c("2012-01-01 00:00:00.000000", "2012-01-01 00:01:01.098307", 
    "2012-01-01 00:03:05.660811", "2012-01-01 00:05:25.413959", "2012-01-01 00:10:10.344876", 
    "2012-01-01 00:11:25.761372"), dateDue = c("2012-01-01 00:30:00.000000", 
    "2012-01-01 00:10:40.024807", "2012-01-01 00:06:26.368941", "2012-01-01 00:09:06.189893", 
    "2012-01-01 00:57:58.998516", "2012-01-01 00:43:24.274176"), 
        dateMatched = c("2012-01-01 00:01:01.098307", "2012-01-01 00:01:01.098307", 
        NA, NA, NA, NA), id = 1:6, created_at = c("2013-12-10 14:37:29.065634", 
        "2013-12-10 14:37:29.065674", "2013-12-10 14:37:29.065701", 
        "2013-12-10 14:37:29.065726", "2013-12-10 14:37:29.065750", 
        "2013-12-10 14:37:29.065775"), updated_at = c(NA_real_, NA_real_, 
        NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_), simulationrun_id = c(7004L, 
        7004L, 7004L, 7004L, 7004L, 7004L), db = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
        1L, 1L)), .Names = c("type", "valuation", "price", "dateCreation", 
    "dateDue", "dateMatched", "id", "created_at", "updated_at", "simulationrun_id", 
    "db"), row.names = c(NA, 6L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: `.SDcols` are the columns to apply the function on. You are applying it to the columns you are using as your id variables in the `ddply` equivalent. I think, just change it to the columns you want to apply the function on. Without seeing what your function is doing it's a bit hard to say.

Comment: @SimonO101, thanks for the quick feedback. I am new to data.table. Maybe you could make that answer a bit more specific? Thanks a lot!

Comment: What @SimonO101 is saying is for you to remove `,.SDcols=c("simulationrun_id", "db")` from your code. `.SDcols` is not what you think it is for. Have a look at `?data.table` for what it is.

Comment: Could you explain what your function is trying to do? Because at the moment, it seems to do a lot of things not the data.table way (ex: you're doing vector scans). Your function might have some nice improvements in terms of speed and code-compactness if you explain what it is you're doing.

Comment: @Arun, I added an explanation.

Comment: @PeterLustig Have your tryed the [dplyr package](https://github.com/hadley/dplyr) It's faster than plyr and more in the SQL style, therefore more intuitive.

Comment: @MartinBel: No, I haven't looked into that. Thanks for the hint, I thought about it, but part of the fun was to get a little more comfortable with data.table.

Comment: @MartínBel, I'm not sure if dplyr's `filter` is faster than `binary search` based subset. And what exactly do you find unintuitive about `data.table` since there's an equivalent to (almost) every operation in SQL :). Check slide 3 [here](http://datatable.r-forge.r-project.org/RFinance2013_Lightning.pdf).

Comment: @MartínBel, I'm curious to see the `dplyr` solution... I can't think of a straightforward way.. Care to attempt an answer? Thanks.

Comment: @Arun Maybe i find it intuitive because i already know some SQL. I believe dplyr is faster than plyr, but not than data.table. I've read this [intro to dplyr](http://rpubs.com/hadley/dplyr-intro) and find it easier to follow than the data.table intro. However, i hope to learn about data table too. I just wanted to add another option. Thanks for the DT resource!

Comment: @MartínBel, I see, thanks for the link. I'll have a look. The problem is also that `dplyr` is designed for a specific set of operations. It's (*relatively*) easier to bullet-point its functions. `data.table` inherits from `data.frame` in that it does much more... It'd be exhaustive to document every combination of usage witin `[..]`. However, the documentation does a descent job of getting you started and the `example(data.table)` gives you a very nice idea of the magic that can be done. Let us know if you've any questions that we can help you with.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

I think this should be faster. There are some errors in the way you use `data.table`. I suggest you read through the introduction, go through examples, and read the FAQ.

```
calcPotentialWelfare <- function(dt){
  NbAsks = nrow(dt["ask", nomatch=0L]) # binary search based subset/join - very fast
  Bids   = dt["bid", nomatch=0L] # binary search based subset/join - very fast
  NbBids = nrow(Bids)
  # for each 'type', the 'valuation' will always be sorted, 
  # but in ascending order - but you need descending order
  # so you can just use the function 'tail' to fetch the last 'n' items... as follows.
  if (NbAsks > 0) return(sum(tail(Bids, min(NbAsks, NbBids))$valuation))
  else return(0)
}

# setkey on 'type' column to use binary search based subset/join in the function
# also on valuation so that we don't have to 'order' for every group 
# inside the function - we can use 'tail'
setkey(orderFlow, type, valuation) 
potentialWelfare.tmp =
  orderFlow[, calcPotentialWelfare(.SD), 
            by=.(simulationrun_id, db),
            .SDcols=c("type", "valuation")]
```

`.SD` is a special variable that creates a data.table for each grouping with all the columns that are not mentioned in `by=` (if `.SDcols` are not specified). If `.SDcols` are specified, then, `.SD` is created for each groupw with just those columns specified, with data corresponding to that group.

Using `lapply(.SD, ...)` provides each column to the function, which is not what you need. You need to send the whole data to the function. However, since you need only the columns 'type' and 'valuation' inside your function, you can speed it up by providing `.SDcols=c('type', 'valuation')`. This'll save a lot of time by ignoring the other columns.

Comment: Thanks! The critical point was my lack of understanding what _.SDcols_ really did. Now, this has become clear.  If I am not mistaken, the whole .SDcols argument could be left out, with corresponding computational performance losses, right?

Comment: Exactly. `.SDcols` is not an absolute requirement. It's to speed up the operations. Imagine a 100 col DT where the operation needs to be performed on 2 cols. We don't have to construct `.SD` for all 100.